# Как создать Docker-окружение с Nginx + PHP 7.4 + Composer

Tags: php, nginx, docker, composer

Подскажите, что должно содержаться в файлах Dockerfile и docker-compose.yml для того, чтобы поднять окружение с nginx, php 7.4 и composer.

Comment: Посмотрите проект [Ларадок](https://github.com/laradock/laradock/blob/master/docker-compose.yml). Там есть все, включая даже больше. Лишнее можно вырезать. Вот вариант покороче https://gist.github.com/michaelneu/2ca7987ef00fa3fbe4fd7b9c07834cc7

Comment: Да, исчерпывающе. Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз уж вы таким образом задаете вопрос, могу вам ответить примерно похоже - Вот ресурс где вы сможете сгенерировать все что вам нужно

https://phpdocker.io/generator

Как это работает, разберетесь потом. Видимо так.
upd. Правда вот про composer я не уверен что в их образе он будет, тем не менее у вас будет с чего начать.

Comment: Большое спасибо. Отличный сервис!